# How To Import CSV Data into MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, pyodbc, mysql-python

When trying to use pyodbc to insert data into a MYSQL Table I get following message:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'SessionID'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#generate data frame with pandas
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\adm_buhe\Documents\order_9b3og4p9wqb876gku.csv')


#db connection settings
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SRV-TASK-HO;'
                      'Database=stat;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
                      
#connection as variable cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()


for row in df:
    cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO dbo.ABB_Charging_Fakten(sessionID, chargerAlias, SN, startTime, endTime, durationHeures, energyDelivered, totalCharge, sessionStatus, idCar, authorizationType, stopReason )
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''',
           row.SessionID,
           row.ChargerAlias,
           row.SN,
           row.StartTime,
           row.EndTime,
           row.Duration,
           row.EnergyDelivered,
           row.TotalCharge,
           row.SessionStatus,
           row.UserName,
           row.AuthorizationType,
           row.StopReason)
           
    
#execute query
conn.commit()
```

Comment: `pandas` has [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to write data ot database

Comment: +1 for using `to_sql()`. BTW, your connection string indicates that you are using MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is you are iterating over the colnames of the df. An easy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( 
  { 
    'Year': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], 
    'Sales': [1000, 2300, 1900, 3400], 
  } 
) 
print(df)

   Year  Sales
0  2018   1000
1  2019   2300
2  2020   1900
3  2021   3400
```

If you just try to iterate over the df:

```
for row in df:
    print(row)
```

Output (which are strings and then python returns an attribute error) :

```
Year
Sales
```

You can use the method `iterrows()` from pandas, which returns a row as a tuple per iteration. (However iterating over rows could be a slow approach for large dataframes)

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
Year     2018
Sales    1000
Name: 0, dtype: int64
Year     2019
Sales    2300
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Year     2020
Sales    1900
Name: 2, dtype: int64
Year     2021
Sales    3400
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

So in this case you can use:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO dbo.ABB_Charging_Fakten(sessionID, chargerAlias, SN, startTime, endTime, durationHeures, energyDelivered, totalCharge, sessionStatus, idCar, authorizationType, stopReason )
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''',
           row.SessionID,
           row.ChargerAlias,
           row.SN,
           row.StartTime,
           row.EndTime,
           row.Duration,
           row.EnergyDelivered,
           row.TotalCharge,
           row.SessionStatus,
           row.UserName,
           row.AuthorizationType,
           row.StopReason)
```

Comment: Hi Roberto, thanks for the suggestion. I applied the code but now I get the error message:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'SessionID'